# How to override default tag css to normal?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Is there a way to make the text wrapped inside `<b> </b>` tag as normal?

I've tried implementing `font-weight: normal !important;` through CSS, but it didn't help. Is it even possible?

Reason of asking this question:

1. I'm writing *print page styling* for a ready made page, so it is not possible for me to get into the code and replace the `<b>` tag.
2. After several failed attempts, I am quite curious to know if it is possible to override *user agent stylesheet* for  tag.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

It is seemingly impossible for me to produce it on jsFiddle.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<figure>
 <i class="icons-i-Spirit"></i>
 <figcaption class="text-uppercase"><b>main spirit</b></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
figcaption {
  font-family: 'TradeGothicW01-BoldCn20_675334';
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: better dont use <b> tag if you need normal text, instead use <span>

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/qw8tx0yc/

Comment: Cannot reproduce the described behavior – I guess there is another rule with `!important` later in the same CSS you are using.

Comment: seems other css is warped  can you show your page code ?

Comment: What is print page styling ? you mean @media print ?

Comment: @Kaushik, I have separate print page which excludes original stylesheet and a fresh one is used just for printing purpose. Some drupal module does that, I've no idea about it.

Comment: Do you need normal font in your printed page for <b>?

Comment: @JacobGray Please check the screenshot I've posted in the question. _User agent Stylesheet_ seems to override my css in my case.

Comment: @VibhorDube post all your CSS in a pastebin and link that, it might make debugging easier.

Comment: @VibhorDube can you share your html block as well ? It seems the hierarchy of html makes trouble for overriding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going wrong in your case:

1. You are applying `css` to the parent of `<b>` tag. Make your code as following:

`figcaption b {
 font-family: 'TradeGothicW01-BoldCn20_675334';
 font-weight: normal !important;
}`

2. Considering your screen-shot, you are making the `CSS` edit which is described in 'Point 1' on Chrome's style editor. Please make the changes in your `CSS` file and then reload your page.

**PS:** I have also been in such situation for hours. It makes you feel quite dumb of yourselves. Don't worry, To err is human!

Comment: What? Seriously? How dumb am I.. :(

Comment: you are over-rating yourself , haha kidding .

Answer (score 1):

A CSS (reset) sheet has probably defined `b{font-weight:normal;}`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqc97v69/)

Comment: If that was the case, then I'd expect the text to already be not-bold so making it not-bold wouldn't be a problem. Your fiddle basically has the code the OP says doesn't work. You don't seem to have been able to reproduce the problem, so this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Just a hint, if the OP doesn't ask a good question, don't even try and answer it, you will usually just draw downvotes.

Comment: @Srinivas: Fiddle surely works, but in my case, it is overriden by _user agent stylesheet_. I've posted the screenshot of Chrome's dev tools.